# aws boto3 moving local script to lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-3.6, boto3

I have a problem with moving my python scripts developed and tested locally to lambda. Basically, the code is different depending on whether I run things locally or by lambda.

As I have multiple aws accounts and credentials, locally I'm using .aws/credentials with multiple profiles.

When I'm developing and testing on my local machine I use `session boto3.session(xxx)` to auth to the correct aws environment. After that to access specific client, I'm using `client = session.client("iam")`, for example:

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name="dev")
iam = session.client("iam")
```

The above works well locally, but when I'm trying to move the script to lambda, it doesn't "recognise" `boto3.session()` and I have to rewrite both lines to one:

```
iam = boto3.client("iam")
```

Comment: `iam = boto3.client("iam)` is missing a closing quote

Comment: thanks! but that does not help with my question :(

Comment: You should be able to do all of this without any explicit code. For running locally, I would set AWS_PROFILE=xyz in the environment before running my Python script (e.g. on Linux simply run "AWS_PROFILE=dev python ./script.py". You don't need to do anything in Lambda as boto3 will retrieve credentials automatically.